# Why engine oils form emulsions?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

Oil and water should not get mixed/emulsified according to the rule that similar dilutes similar.

What is the reason that they form an emulsion in crankcases when there is water ingress?

Comment: There are additives.

Comment: @DKNguyen additives which are surfactants and stabilize the emulsion?

Comment: I don't think the goal is to stabilize the emulsion as far as water is concerned. At least not all the time. I think a lot of the time it has some other purpose and that is a side effect.

Comment: @DKNguyen I see, thanks

Comment: "not get mixed" - true. "emulsified" - not true. Provide enough sufficiently vigorous mixing of two liquids that can not be mixed, and you get an emulsion. Sure there are additives that can speed it up and situations where it's impossible for unrelated reasons (like, sufficient mixing will produce too much heat, causing boil-off), but emulsion is the essential "end-game" state of mixing dissimilar.

Answer (score 1):

#### It's just their physical properties

Water and oil are [immiscible](https://www.google.com/search?q=immiscible&rlz=1C1ONGR_enUS1043US1043&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), meaning they don't mix together when put together, like water and alcohol.  So what happens when they are mixed and agitated (like by the crankshaft) is they form an [emulsion](https://www.google.com/search?q=emulsion&rlz=1C1ONGR_enUS1043US1043&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  Milk & margarine are emulsions.

The most common source of water in the crankcase is water vapor, which is a combustion by-product.  Combustion gasses get past the piston rings.  We manage this blow-by via Positive Crankcase Ventilation, which draws a vacuum on the crankcase and draws these vapors back to the engine inlet.  Some of that water vapor, however, may condense when the engine is cool, resulting in water droplets in the crankcase and thus in the oil.  So the two mix together.  These water droplets will evaporate when the engine gets up to normal operating temperature.

Water in the crankcase leads to reduced oil performance and the risk of corrosion, so the control is a properly spec'ed piston/cylinder design and crankcase ventilation.  Large marine engines may employ heating to minimize condensation at startup.

Answer (score 1):

There are additives to the oil that can emulsify water with oil. Sometimes it helps to spread any water present throughout the oil rather than letting it collect which can help keep water away from the metal when there is only a small amount of water in a much larger volume of oil. However, is is not always the goal of the additives.

Often it is a side-effect of additives added for some other purpose (such as cleaning deposits and gunk in the engine). Detergents generally behave this way.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern motor oils contain detergent additives, these hold dirt in suspension so that the oil filter can remove them from the lubrication system. This also means that any water in the oil gets emulsified and turned into "mustard" by the detergent.

Before engines had oil filters, they ran on *non-detergent oil* in which the dirt settled out in the bottom of the oil pan each time the engine was shut down, forming a layer of *sludge* in which the dirt was more or less trapped until the pan was pulled and scraped out.